# How to implement a react js websocket client?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, websocket

I want to create a react js application as a web-socket client, In which react js will request a server which I'm already created in node js and working on port no 1234.

I'm beginner to react js. In my application react js client is not requesting to node js server. what I'm missing in following code?

**Node_js Server-**

```
var server = require('websocket').server, http = require('http');
require('events').EventEmitter.prototype._maxListeners = 100;
nconf = require('nconf');
var socket = null;
var connection = null;
var filePath = ''
var timeInteval = 0
var LineByLineReader;
var sleep = require('sleep');

function init(){
   nconf.argv().env().file({file: 'config.json'});
   filePath = nconf.get('file-path');
   timeInteval = nconf.get('time-inteval');
}

var main = function () {
   init(); 
   socket = new server({
       httpServer: http.createServer().listen(1234)
   });
   console.log('Waiting for Client... On Port No : 1234');

socket.on('request', function (request) {
    connection = request.accept(null, request.origin);
    var connections = []
    connections.push(connection);

    console.log(connection.remoteAddress + '=====>>> Connection accepted.');
    var lineReader = require('line-reader');
    lineReader.eachLine(filePath, function(line, last) {
        for (var i = 0; i < connections.length; i++) {
            connections[i].sendUTF(line);
        }
        sleep.sleep(timeInteval)
    });

    connection.on('message', function (message) {

    });

    connection.on('close', function (connection) {
        console.log('=====>>> Connection closed');
        var index = connections.indexOf(connection);
        connections.splice(index, 1);
    });
    connection.on('error', function (connection) {
        console.log(connection.remoteAddress + ' : error');
    });
});
}

if (require.main === module) { 
   main(); 
}
```

This node js server is working fine for any number of clients.

**App.jsx -**

```
var React = require('react')
var ws = require('ws');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

const Echo = React.createClass({
    getInitialState(){
        return { messages : [] }
    },
    componentDidMount: function() {
        var wsc = new ws('ws://localhost:1234');
        wsc.onmessage = function(message) {
            this.setState({ messages: message.data });
        }.bind(this);
    },
    render: function() {
        return ( this.state.messages );
    }
});

const component = ReactDOM.render(
   <Echo />,
   document.getElementById('container')
);
```

**index.html-**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">

<head>
  <meta charset = "UTF-8">
  <title>React App</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
  </div>
  <script src = "index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**webpack.config.js-**

```
var config = {
entry: './App.jsx',
output: {
  path:'./',
  filename: 'index.js',
},
devServer: {
  inline: true,
  port: 8090
},
module: {
  loaders: [
     {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel',

        query: {
           presets: ['es2015', 'react']
        }
     }
  ]
}
}
module.exports = config;
```

Comment: Where are you sending the `request` how do you send `messages` ? Your code seems to be incomplete, this is not a special React question, have you a working example with another client?

Comment: @webdeb - from App.jsx I'm sending request to websocket server. From node js code I'm sending messages to the websocket connected clients. yes this node js code is working fine with java websocket clients so it is not incomplete. In react js what I'm missing ?

Comment: any errors in the console?

Comment: @webdeb - no on console showing bundle is now valid but I go to url http:/localhost:8090 blank page is there.

Comment: try to render something like `<h1>hello</h1>` then its not clear what your messages are an array? or a string?